# Question about Real and Complex primes (Algebraic number theory)

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I posted same question ago, but there was no answer.

I'm reading Jurgen Neukirch, Algebraic number theory, p.183

[image]

[image]

Now I can't understand the underlined statement.
Why that  $\mathfrak{p}$ is real or complex embedding depends whether the $K_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ or to $\mathbb{C}$? (By the Ostrowski theorem, $K_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$)

Comment: Just think about the closure of a subfield $K$ of $\mathbf C$.  The field $K$ already contains $\mathbf Q$, so the closure at least includes $\mathbf R$.  What could the closure be if it is bigger than $\mathbf R$?

Answer (score 1):

The completions of an embedding is either $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, depending on wheter the embedding is real or not (this is trivial!).

Now we know that if $v$ is an archimedian valuation on $K$ then up to equivalence $v$ comes from an (archimedic) embedding of $K$. This means that the bijection into the embedding is isometric under the valuation. Note that in $\mathbb R/\mathbb C$ there is only one valuation up to equivalence.

So if we take the completion $K_v$ it must be isomorphic to the completion of the embedding, which is either $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, depending on whether the embedding is real.

Comment: Yes, I somewhat understand. Thank you. Uhm. Where can I found a proof of the uniqueness of (archimedean?) valuation on R/C up to equivalence? Why?